# Accessing Sharepoint database to read all blob data

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, blob

I have a situation where I am uploading an image in sharepoint and it is being saved using blob.  I need to create an XML file with the data of the blob and other data that helps users to identify it. The following is a hint of what I want

```
<image>
    <name>mydog</name>
    <extension>.jpg</extension>
    <blobid>0234234</blobid>
    <blobpath>435343445</blobpath> </image>
```

I was looking at the tables in wss_content and came up to alldocumentstreams where there is a column called rbsid.  unfortunately I cannot link this id to non of my documents. My question is this is there a way how i can get all the blob information from the DB so i can link it to other details?

Comment: Yes there is, if you would consider using an ADO.NET adapter for SharePoint.

Comment: i am considering everything at the moment.  all i want is to get the file path where the blob file is and the blob name for that particular file.  Can you please help me out to understand how this can be done?

Comment: One of us is missing the point - the blob is stored in the database - stored in a file mixed in with gazillions of bytes of other data. It isn't just a file on its own.

Comment: Sure, but I need some more info. Is the file stored in a list or in a document library?

Comment: documents are being uploaded in a list and there will be no alterations to it for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Directly accessing the SharePoint database [isn't supported by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb861829%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

> If a server component requires information from the database, it must
>   get that data by using the appropriate items in the SharePoint object
>   model, and not by trying to get the items from the data structures in
>   the database through some query mechanism.

You might be better using the SharePoint object model to read these files.

Some links that should help

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/File_Shunter.aspx
- http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2011/04/01/read-a-file-in-sharepoint-document-library/

Comment: Is there a way to create an XML file with metadata in the same directory where the blob column saves the actual data file?

Comment: The blob column doesn't save a file in a directory (unless you're using external blob storage, but thats another story) a better way of doing this is storing metadata in columns in the document library - see that first link for details.

Comment: hi ryan, 10x for your answer.  so aparently one cannot get the physical path where the binary data is neither through code nor through sql?  Manually i found the path where the blobs are being saved and i know it is C:\Sharepoint\2342..... There is no way I can get that?